# PHPUnit Test Directory "..." not found: interpreting "." literally instead of current directory?

Tags: php, docker-compose, phpunit, phpstorm

I am getting the error, all of the sudden, that the test directory specified in phpunit.xml config file is not found; I can see that it is interpreting the period literally instead of "the current directory":

```
[docker-compose://[/Users/jordan/git/jj/docker-compose.yml]:apache/]:php /var/www/html/restapp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --bootstrap /var/www/html/restapp/rest/bootstrap.php --configuration /var/www/html/restapp/rest/phpunit.xml --teamcity

Test directory "/var/www/html/restapp/rest/tests/./internal/marking" not found
                                                 ^ start of path in <directory>
```

Why is it trying to interpret the period literally? What have I changed all the sudden that has stopped it from working?

Comment: Could you share what you have on your `phpunit.xml` or at least the part you are referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test configuration in PhpStorm is not configured properly. Check out screenshots.

[image: 2]

[image: 1]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I didn't include enough information in my question: to test it wasn't PHPStorm I tried on the command executing ./phpunit and it still gave me the same error. So, I knew it was in my phpunit.xml. Turns out, the error is basically just pointing in the wrong direction and made me think it was interpreting the period literally. The answer was that the directory indeed did not exist. Thank you and @matiaslauriti for your help.